# document.getElementById("myB").style.top = "100px";

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there a way to set style.top to be a variable instead of px?

I want the div to change a absolute position when i push a button to a random value instead of a constant

```
<div class="dot" id="dot1" style="top:180px;left:280px"></div>

function myFunction1(){
    var x1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 150) + 75);
    var y1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 150) + 75);

    console.log(x1);
    console.log(y1);


   //this works
   document.getElementById("dot1").style.top = "100px";
   document.getElementById("dot1").style.top = "100px";

   //this doesnt
   document.getElementById("dot1").style.top = x1;
   document.getElementById("dot1").style.top = y1;
   }
```

Comment: Check if this helps you: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_css.asp

Comment: you should set property to `document.getElementById('dot1').style.setProperty(...`

Comment: `x1` and `y1`are variables so you shouldn't have quotes around them

Comment: I didnt get this to work either: document.getElementById('dot1').style.setProperty('top',x1)

Comment: You can use a variable if you like. Lengths in CSS still need units, so the variable has to include units.

Comment: @Quentin NICEEEEEEEEEEE 

Answer (score 0):

`document.documentElement.style.top = x1`. Same thing with left property.